# Speed up javascript animation by specifying the point of time when css rules should apply

Tags: javascript, animation

Suppose I have 10 elements on a page.

At the current moment I'm iterating them in a loop changing width and position:

```
el[i].style.width = ....
el[i].style.left = ....
```

I'm wondering if the animation could run faster if I tell the browser to re-render all elements only once, after the loop has finished

Comment: Are CSS3 or jQuery options?

Comment: Predefined CSS3 styles is not an option, since I'm writing a game with moving elements

Comment: You could use transitions... `transition:all 1s linear;` So when you change any property on the element, it will be transitioned to its new value. If need be, you could specify separate transitions for each property that you care about: `transition:width 1s linear, left .5s ease-in-out;` etc

Comment: jQuery is not an option. jQuery is 'code fast, play slow'

Comment: I want the page to be re-rendered after I have applied 20 CSS rules. By now page is re-rendered 20 times, sadly

Comment: ~~~~This means I should tel the rendering engine to 'freeze'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS3 is faster and you will have to code a lot less, have a look at this [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aconaj/3/), I just did two examples, one with [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions) (.anima2) and the other with [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) (.anima). With JS you just have to apply and remove the classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the change to a shared class or load a style sheet with all changes in it this will make all changes apply at the same time, not sure about performance impact though...

Comment: I am calculating CSS rules using some formula, no chances to predict the numbers )

Answer (score 0):

To be investigated by me (not fully cross browser, behaviour differs and changes, this needs heavy work of testing abd benchmarking):

a) `requestAnimationFrame`

b) CSS `translate3d` and other new CSS3 instead of `left` for GPU optimization

Come back later and I'll tell the results